# Problem with Placeholder, it's not moving as supposed to

Tags: css, sass, placeholder

I don't know why it doesn't move, I'd like to know what's wrong

Here is the css (sass)

```
.find-property-main
    .custom-inputs
        position: relative
        display: inline-block
        .placeholder-label
            bottom: -1px !important
            font-size: 0.8rem
            text-transform: uppercase
            color: #707274 !important
            position: absolute
            pointer-events: none
            @include customize-transition ($duracion: 0.5s)         
        .placeholder-input
            font-size: 0.8rem
            text-transform: uppercase
            border: none
            border-bottom: solid 2px #ced4da
            border-radius: 0
            margin: 0
            padding: 0
            height: calc(1rem + 0.75rem + 2px)


.custom-inputs input:focus ~ .placeholder-label, .custom-inputs input:not(:focus):valid ~ .placeholder-label
    bottom: 12px !important
    font-size: 0.7rem
    font-weight: bold
    color: rgb(17, 38, 78)
```

Here is the HTML

```
<form action="#" method="$_POST" class="border p-5 find-property-main">                         
   <div class="form-form col-3 custom-inputs">
   <label class="placeholder-label">Tamaño</label>
   <input list="casa" type="text" class="form-control placeholder-input" placeholder="">
   <datalist id="casa">
     <option value="Pequeña">
     </option>
     <option value="Mediana">
     </option>
     <option value="Grande">
     </option>
   </datalist>
</div>
```

I have already reviewed it, and apparently everything is fine, but when I try to enter data the label does not move.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is English only, please either translate your post or ask it on the Spanish version at https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your selector targets a `<label />` which has a focused `<input />` as predecessor. But in your *html*, the label comes first and the input after it. In order for the selector to work, you would have to switch them around:

```html
<form action="#" method="$_POST" class="border p-5 find-property-main">                         
   <div class="form-form col-3 custom-inputs">
   <input list="casa" type="text" class="form-control placeholder-input" placeholder="">
   <label class="placeholder-label">Tamaño</label>
   <datalist id="casa">
     <option value="Pequeña">
     </option>
     <option value="Mediana">
     </option>
     <option value="Grande">
     </option>
   </datalist>
</div>
```